# Can't figure out Web2py Ticket error its odd

Tags: python, sqlite, web2py

I'm new to Web2py and am unable to understand the error that the ticket is throwing up. Can someone explain the error and why it is occurring?

```
Ticket ID
127.0.0.1.2016-05-28.15-45-10.493c5f3c-e5f2-4034-8e82-69637b1fcc35

<type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'> invalid table/column name "size" is a "ALL" reserved SQL/NOSQL keyword

Version
web2py™ Version 2.12.1-stable+timestamp.2015.08.07.07.22.06

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sharankumar\Desktop\New\gluon\restricted.py", line 227, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "C:/Users/sharankumar/Desktop/New/applications/MyLogin/models/db.py", line 232, in <module>
    format='%(name)s')
  File "C:\Users\sharankumar\Desktop\New\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\base.py", line 817, in define_table
    table = self.lazy_define_table(tablename,*fields,**args)
  File "C:\Users\sharankumar\Desktop\New\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\base.py", line 834, in lazy_define_table
    table = table_class(self, tablename, *fields, **args)
  File "C:\Users\sharankumar\Desktop\New\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\objects.py", line 351, in __init__
    check_reserved(field_name)
  File "C:\Users\sharankumar\Desktop\New\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\base.py", line 519, in check_reserved_keyword
    'invalid table/column name "%s" is a "%s" reserved SQL/NOSQL keyword' % (name, backend.upper()))
SyntaxError: invalid table/column name "size" is a "ALL" reserved SQL/NOSQL keyword
```

Comment: You are trying to name a column "size" which seems to be forbidden because it's a reserved word. Pick another name.

Comment: where should i change that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `db.define_table()`, it appears you have attempted to create a field named "size", which is not allowed because it is a SQL reserved word. You should either change the field name or use the "rname" argument to specify a different name for the database to use:

```
    Field('size', rname='object_size', ...)
```

With the above, you can use the name "size" in all of your Python code, but the database will actually create a field with the name "object_size".